# Uncaught TypeError: db.collection is not a function for a real-time database in firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

when I try to access my collection I get the following error. My firebase app is initialized inside my main app component.

I didn't include the config object here but I know that it works because I'm also using firebase auth in my app which works perfectly fine.
App.js

```
componentDidMount(){
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
}
```

Component where I am trying to make a db call

```
componentDidMount(){

const db = firebase.database();
const ref = db.collection('Users/Notes').doc()

  let getDoc = ref.get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
  });
}
```

I am rendering this component immediately by including it in App.js, I don't know if that might somehow be a problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're mixing up Firebase database products.

`firebase.database()` gives you an object to deal with data in Firebase Realtime Database.  But the code you're writing to work with that object looks like it's using the Firestore API, which is a completely different database product.

If you want an object that lets you make queries against Firestore collections, you should use `firebase.firestore()`, and you will need to import the library that gives you access to that API.

To be sure that you're using the correct database, please review the documentation for getting started with both [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

Comment: Yes thank you i was looking at firestore documentation instead of realtime :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
const db = firebase.database();
```

into this:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

More info [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize)